# MongoDB update or create or/and replace with multiple condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, upsert

I'm trying to update, create or replace some field in my collection depending on 3 conditions.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "abcd",
    "usersession": 
    [
      {
        "userId" : "req.user._id",
        "date" :
        [
          {
            "day" : "14/11/2021",
            "sessionday": 
            [
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "day" : "15/11/2021",
            "sessionday": 
            [
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "userId" : "req.user._id2",
        "date" :
        [
          {
            "day" : "01/01/2021",
            "sessionday": 
            [
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer2",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress2"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer2",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "day" : "25/05/2021",
            "sessionday": 
            [
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer2",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress2"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer2",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress2"
              },
              {
                "hour": "%hh%mm%ss",
                "referer": "req.headers.referer2",
                "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   
  }
]
```

1. if req.user._id exist on userId then if new date() format %dd%MM%YY exist in day then add new fields :

   - `"hour" : new date() format %hh%mm%ss`
   - `"referer": req.headers.referer`
   - `"ip": req.socket.remoteAddress`
2. if req.user._id exist on userId then if new date() format %dd%MM%YY doesn't exist in day then add new fields :
   -

   "day" : "14/11/2021",
   "sessionday":
   [
   {
   "hour": new date(format:%hh%mm%ss),
   "referer": req.headers.referer,
   "ip": req.socket.remoteAddress
   },
   ]
3. if req.user._id exist doesn't exist on userId then add new fields :
   -

   "userId" : req.user._id,
   "date" :
   [
   {
   "day" : "14/11/2021",
   "sessionday":
   [
   {
   "hour": new date(format:%hh%mm%ss),
   "referer": "req.headers.referer",
   "ip": "req.socket.remoteAddress"
   },
   ]
   ]
   },
4. if day>=10 then replace oldest date with newone

Is possible to do this with one aggregate or update ?

```
db.users-sessions.aggregate

db.users-sessions.updateOne
```

with maybe :  `$switch, $set, $eq, upsert, $addFields, $cond, $match, $and, $or, { $exists: true }, format: "%d%m%Y", $concat, then`

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vm-btDBi0eB

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Date/time values should **never** be stored as strings, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Comment: is ok if I do ?
let date= new Date();
let dateDay = date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear();